# Verificar se os valores de uma array são todos iguais ou todos diferentes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Queria alguma função que retornasse TRUE quando todos os valores dentro de uma array fosse igual ou se todos fossem diferentes, e retornasse FALSE se não fossem todas iguais e nem todas diferentes. Caso não tenha entendido, explicarei com exemplos:

**Ex:** 
 Caso eu tenha a(s) seguinte(s) array(s) para verificação:

```
var arr = ['xx','xx','xx']; //(todos iguais)
     //ou
var arr = ['xx','yy','zz']; //(todos diferentes)
```

A função retornaria TRUE, porém se fosse uma array na qual os valores não são todos iguais nem todos diferentes retornaria FALSE, como na seguinte situação:

```
var arr = ['xx','xx','zz']; //(Os valores não todos iguais, e nem todos diferentes)
```

Eai? Alguém tem alguma ideia de como posso fazer isso?

Comment: O que você já tentou?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Filtrei o array removendo os duplicados. Se só sobrou um elemento, todos são iguais. Se o tamanho do array for o mesmo, todos são diferentes.

```
function todosIguaisOuDiferentes(array) {
    var filtrado = array.filter(function(elem, pos, arr) {
        return arr.indexOf(elem) == pos;
    });

    return filtrado.length === 1 || filtrado.length === array.length; 
}
```

Comment: +1 ... Código legível, curto e inteligente.

Comment: Vlw, funcionou aqui! : )

Answer (score 2):

```js
Array.prototype.allValuesSame = function() {
  for (var i = 1; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (this[i] !== this[0])
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}

var arr = ['xx', 'xx', 'xx']; //(todos iguais)
var arr2 = ['xx', 'yy', 'zz']; //(todos diferentes)

console.log(arr.allValuesSame()); // true
console.log(arr2.allValuesSame()); // false
```

Comment: Quando são todos diferentes tem que retornar true também, pelo o que entendi.

Comment: Deve retornar true se todos forem iguais ou todos diferentes. Essa resposta está incorreta.

Comment: Entendi, esqueci esse detalhe,  vou editar esta resposta.

Answer (score 1):

```
function CheckArray (a) {
    if (a.length == 1)
        return true;

    var result = false;

    // Verifica se são todos iguais
    for(var i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (!(a[0] === a[i])) {
            result = false;
            break;
        } else {
            result = true;
        }
    }
    if (result)
        return true;

    // Verifica se são todos diferentes
    result = true;
    for (var i = a.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        // Caso o indexOf e o lastIndexOf sejam diferentes, isso indica que há duas ocorrências e portanto não são todos diferentes.
        if (a.indexOf(a[i]) != a.lastIndexOf(a[i])) {
            result = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Não está exatamente um código elegante, mas pelo o que testei funciona.